# How to read data in highcharts using screenreaders (NVDA)

Tags: highcharts, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I am using NVDA to check the accessibility of highcharts and the screen reader does not read the contents inside the highcharts. I cannot use the tab or arrow keys to go to the next value and read the screen. I tried including the accessibility.js module of highcharts.

Sample code I tried:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var chart = {
        type: 'column'
      };
      var title = {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
      };
      var subtitle = {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
      };
      var xAxis = {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
          'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
      };
      var yAxis = {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
      };
      var tooltip = {
        headerFormat: '<span style = "font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style = "color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
          '<td style = "padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
      };
      var plotOptions = {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      };
      var credits = {
        enabled: false
      };
      var series = [{
          name: 'Tokyo',
          data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6,
            148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'New York',
          data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3,
            91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'London',
          data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6,
            52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Berlin',
          data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4,
            47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1
          ]
        }
      ];

      var json = {};
      json.chart = chart;
      json.title = title;
      json.subtitle = subtitle;
      json.tooltip = tooltip;
      json.xAxis = xAxis;
      json.yAxis = yAxis;
      json.series = series;
      json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
      json.credits = credits;
      $('#container').highcharts(json);

    });
  </script>
```

While using the tab key on the column chart NVDA just reads details about the highcharts and then it reads the 1st column. Cannot navigate to other columns, if I press the tab again the control goes to the legend part.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here, in form of a code snippet?

Comment: Even if you managed to render a chart accessible to screen readers, I believe the best practice is to provide the table along with the diagram. In any case, the annotations in the diagram would resemble those of a table.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to integrate the sample code as a code snippet?

Comment: yes sure will do that

Comment: @Andy While using the tab key on the column chart NVDA just reads details about the highcharts and then it reads the 1st column. Cannot navigate to other columns, if I press the tab again the control goes to the legend part.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is alright, Highcharts seems to have excellent accessibility support. Good choice!

The issue is a misunderstanding regarding keyboard navigation.

As per [Aria Practices’ Keyboard Navigation Inside Components](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-6-keyboard-navigation-inside-components):

> […] the tab sequence should include only one focusable element of a composite UI component. Once a composite contains focus, keys other than Tab and Shift + Tab enable the user to move focus among its focusable elements.

These keys other than <kbd>Tab</kbd> usually are the *arrow keys*, which is exactly what Highcharts is doing.

In your example you can switch months by means of Left and Right keys, and inside a month by means of Up and Down arrow keys. There are accessible names and regions, so screen readers should announce the data well.

For more details see also [Highcharts for Accessibility](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/accessibility)

Comment: Hey Andy,

Thank you so much for the reply, I am sorry that I took this long.

When using the screenreader NVDA the arrow keys seemed to be not working.
Now one of my teammates has found out in an online article that using the Insert key with < and > arrow keys will read the columns of the chart.

Comment: Hei, no worries. The insert key is the modifier key for NVDA. [I cannot find that key combination](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvdaTracAttachments/455/keycommands%20with%20laptop%20keyboard%20layout.html#8), but I’m assuming that it’s simply reading the columns, not controlling focus. I found that using Alt+arrow keys would do the trick. Does that work for you?

Comment: Apparently, the Highcharts element is lacking a `widget` or [`application` role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#application), so the screen reader will intercept arrow key events for reading.

Comment: Hi Andy, Yes Alt + arrow key is working fine for me. I also have one doubt when there is no data or it is 0 for a particular column NVDA reads blank, have you encountered this issue?